# Fatal error: Call to undefined method WFEditor::getContext() in ......../administrator/components/com_jce/models/model.php on line 128

Tags: php, joomla-3.6, jce

I am unable to login into back end of joomla, i am using joomla 3.6 and when i operate PHP Version 7.0.12 and try login, i get

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method WFEditor::getContext() in ......../administrator/components/com_jce/models/model.php on line 128

but while using PHP Version 5.4.43 the administrator/index.php page does not even load.

**Solution**

The way i solved it was by going into phpMyAdmin (database) and disable the component that was causing problem (in this case JCE) and now I was able to login and updated the component.

Worked back  then.

Comment: Why dont you report this error to the JCE team? https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/contact/administrator

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an extension specific bug